# How do you create a negative and positive voltage(-6V and 6V) with a singular voltage source?

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits

I'm trying to use a battery to activate an op amp schmitt trigger but learned that there needs to be both a positive and negative voltage supplied to Vcc+ and Vcc-. I've seen a lot of schematics online that show using a secondary voltage source for this purpose but I can't do that due restrictions of my circuit.

EDIT: Here are extra details to clarify the circuit:
input battery voltage: 14.8V-12.3V(14.8V at max charge, 12.2V max depleted voltage before the battery starts taking damage)

EDIT 2: add a better labeled diagram and added second full schematic the op amp schmitt trigger is supposed to be a part of.

Trigger voltages: I want the op amp to send a signal while 12.2V < Vss and stop at 12.2 >= Vss. (ignore my earlier comment saying 12.3V is the shutoff point, read my schematic wrong)

[image]

How would I create both a negative and positive voltage for the vcc+ and vcc- connections of the op amp with only a singular voltage source?

[image]

Comment: the output of the op amp is going to switch on a mosfet gate so I need them to be  -3-5V on vcc- and 3-5V on vcc+. Im using a 14.8V-12.3V voltage source for this.

Comment: Please edit your question to give the specification for input voltage range and trigger voltages / hysteresis. You might not require a dual supply. By the way, you have a dead-short to ground on the output. Your simulation isn't going to tell you anything.

Comment: added changes, forgot to put a resistor at the end representing load, circuit still doesn't work but I hope I made things clearer.

Comment: You are mentioning Vcc+, Vcc- and Vss, none of which are labelled on your schematic, none of your resistors are labeled and you have a battery which might be the battery you're trying to monitor. Where is the supply for the circuit coming from? Can you explain your thought process for the circuit you came up with? I suspect you are trying to make a comparator circuit with some hysteresis. This will compare one input with another and switch on the transition of one relative to the other.

Comment: Labeled Vcc+, Vcc-, and Vss now. Also yes, i'm trying to have the battery monitor its self, i'll put the full schematic in since it seems relevant now. Also yes, i'm trying to make a op amp with hysteresis.

Comment: Is this for an automotive application?

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer. More later - maybe!

[image]

*Figure 1. OP's circuit.*

There are a number of problems with your circuit.

- Your op-amp VCC+ is fed through a 5.6 MΩ resistor. The [datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AS358-358A-358B.pdf) says that the quiescent current, I<sub>CC</sub>, is 0.7 mA. From Ohm's Law we can see that you would need a supply of V = IR = 0.7m × 5.6M = 3920 V just to power up the op-amp. With a 12 V battery you're a tad short of adequate voltage.
- Zener diodes will drop voltage when reverse biased *and* current is flowing through them. You have them connected directly to the inverting input of your op-amp which has a very high input impedance and has an input bias current of 20 nA and the datasheet doesn't specify whether this is in or out. This won't be enough to to cause diode breakdown.
- You seem to be trying to decrease the inverting input by 3.6 + 4.7 × 2 = 13 V. Presumably this is to compare with the voltage at the non-inverting input but the voltage at this input will switch between 4 V and 8 V, depending on the state of the op-amp output.

You really can't just cobble together circuits like this without better understanding.

> I'm trying to use a battery to activate an op-amp Schmitt trigger but learned that there needs to be both a positive and negative voltage supplied to Vcc+ and Vcc-.

No. Single-ended supply, V+ and GND, will be fine for your application.

> I've seen a lot of schematics online that show using a secondary voltage source for this purpose but I can't do that due restrictions of my circuit.

You can power the circuit from the battery being monitored.

> Here are extra details to clarify the circuit: input battery voltage: 14.8V-12.3V(14.8V at max charge, 12.2V max depleted voltage before the battery starts taking damage)
>
> Trigger voltages: I want the op amp to send a signal while 12.2V < Vss and stop at 12.2 >= Vss.

We can write this more clearly as:

- Output enabled when V<sub>SS</sub> ≥ 12.6 V.
- Output disabled when V<sub>SS</sub> ≤ 12.2 V.

The difference between the two is the *hysteresis* and you need to check that the values you choose are correct. If you set the hysteresis to finely then the act of switching on the load will cause the battery voltage to sag which will switch the load off which will allow the battery voltage to rise which will cause the load to switch on again which ...

When you get a proper comparator circuit and decide on the level of hysteresis you want you can do the calculations. Texas Instruments have a [Comparator with Hysteresis Reference Design](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu020a/tidu020a.pdf) application note but it may be a bit advanced for you. DayCounter's [Comparator Hysteresis Calculator](https://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Comparator-Hysteresis-Calculator.phtml) may be more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple circuit that I have used to create dual power supplies with a single power source for prototyping purposes. Depending on the current draw size resistors and capacitors. There are elegant solutions widely available.

[image: Simple dual supply from a single source]

An elegant solution would be to use a MAX1044 / ICL7660 Switched-Capacitor Voltage Converter. Below is a high level diagram.

[image: Max1044 / ICL7660 high level diagram]

Alternate solution would be MAX660. Below is a high level application diagram.

[image: MAX660 application diagram]

Additional solution would be to use LTC1044/7660. Below is a high level circuit diagram.

[image: LTC1044 / 7660 Switch capacitor voltage Converter circuit diagram]

---

**References:**

- [MAX1044/ICL7660 Switched-Capacitor Voltage Converter](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/ICL7660-MAX1044.pdf)
- [MAX660 Switched Capacitor Voltage Converter](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max660.pdf)
- [LTC1044/7660 Switched Capacitor Voltage Converter](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC1044_7660.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, if you are using batteries. For example, if the circuit requires -6V-0-+6V, you get two 6 volt batteries, wire them in series, and bring out a wire from their junction point. The junction wire serves as the 0 volt point, the top of the battery stack is then at +6 volts and the bottom is at -6 volts, relative to the junction wire.

Comment: that would require two voltage sources which is what I said I wanted to avoid. I'd need to double my number of batteries and double the cost of my batteries for a single op amp in order to do that and still meet power requirements of my circuit

Answer (score 0):

In case, the current requirement is low you can tap the zero volt from the mid point of a uniform restrictive potentiometer

[image].

Note: energy loss will be significant

Comment: Forgot to add the current requirement but it is going to reach 9.2A, and this would require me to get a 2x bigger battery then the one I have